# Spark gives OOM when selecting 10GB data from msql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jvm

I am running my job in a standalone cluster with one master and slave and have my spark cluster config as below:

```
CPU cores - 4
RAM - 16GB
```

While doing spark-submit I am giving `-executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 10g`. The job works fine with 5GB of data. I see `block manager size 502MB` in the logs when I run the job.

**Code structure:**

```
df = sc.read.format('jdbc').options(driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', url=jdbc_url, dbtable=query_str,numPartitions=12,partitionColumn="cord_uid",lowerBound=1,upperBound=12).load()
df.write.csv(s3_bucketname, mode="append")
```

**Error log**

```
     2020-06-05 16:08:26,064 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 7.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 7) in 476230 ms on <container_ip>(executor 0) (9/11)
2020-06-05 16:09:14,289 INFO client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200605154949-0013/0 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
2020-06-05 16:09:14,315 INFO cluster.StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20200605154949-0013/0 removed: Command exited with code 1
2020-06-05 16:09:14,323 INFO client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200605154949-0013/1 on worker-20200605114514-172.26.0.5-41969 (<container_ip>:41969) with 3 core(s)
2020-06-05 16:09:14,324 INFO cluster.StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200605154949-0013/1 on hostPort <container_ip>:41969 with 3 core(s), 10.0 GB RAM
2020-06-05 16:09:14,324 INFO client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200605154949-0013/1 is now RUNNING
2020-06-05 16:09:14,334 ERROR scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 0 on <container_ip>: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

**Do I need to clean up the block manager meomory by setting some property because I can see even for the finished tasks it is not free the memory?**

Comment: can you show query ?? & also can you post spark ui page ?

Comment: the query is select * from table name, i have some problem accessing spark UI but if you want i can paste the full logs? @Srinivas

Comment: ok, can you check is all executors are fetching data or only one executor is running ??

Comment: i think there is just a single executor because once it fails, it is trying for creating more such executors. I have updated the logs now. @Srinivas

Answer (score 1):

Try to set below config option & To fetch data parallel using multiple executors, hence chances of getting OOM is very low.

```
partitionColumn - Partition Column
lowerBound  - <lowest partition number>
upperBound  - <largest partition number>
numPartitions - <number of partitions>
```

Comment: I have tried the  df repartition strategy to the number of cores but still, it was failing.

Comment: I think repartition will not work here. above options will directly execute in database & based on that it will start fetch data.

Comment: Does that mean it will fetch the data in chunks?

Comment: Yes, say for example if you have 100 records in database, using above options value for numPartitions value is 10 means 100/10 = 10 threads will start fetching data of 10 rows each.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215362/discussion-between-user7422128-and-srinivas).

Comment: The above problem is resolved now I am able to create multiple tasks out of it, but with too many tasks even it is getting failed. I increased the number of partitions and it got failed with java heap space errors, Should there be any limit on the number of partitions defined when reading the data frame from MYSQL? @Srinivas

Comment: Check above params are using correctly or not .. if you are using wrongly its will effect your source database, i forget to mention this point in previous point.

Comment: Yes I can see in the logs it is using them .numPartitions=12,partitionColumn="cord_uid",lowerBound=1,upperBound=12 . The problem is doubling the data is failing the program. Should it matter if the size of the data is doubled or triple? @Srinivas

Comment: I think you are using options are wrong .. if you use correctly it will not double or triple your data.. :)

Comment: this is the only code i am using : 
df = sc.read.format('jdbc').options(driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', url=jdbc_url, dbtable=query_str,numPartitions=12,partitionColumn="cord_uid",lowerBound=1,upperBound=12).load()
df.write.csv(s3_bucketname, mode="append") @Srinivas

Comment: can i process any amount of data with this config @Srinivas?

Comment: yes, you can but you have to choose proper values of above config, for example if you choose partitionColumn as id or sequence id .. its not good as per each partition there will be one row.

Comment: Finally, the problem is resolved by keeping the partition size not more than 1gb, otherwise, it fails. the data should be distributed efficiently else it will fail anywhere.